# Maven 3 - Distribute custom plugin in a .jar?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Complete Maven newb here, so forgive any abused terminology, etc.

I've built a custom plugin in Maven 3 (one that defines goals for git rebase).  I'm able to:

```
mvn install
```

No problem.  I can then invoke the goal from the command line:

```
mvn edu.clemson.cs.rsrg:git-plugin:rebase
```

Everything's golden.  I have this lovely git-plugin-XXX.jar file sitting in my `target` directory.

I'd like to make my custom goals available to another project such that when other members of the dev team pull down that project's source, they get my plugin for free (or at least, after a `mvn build`).

My understanding is that the purist solution is to set up a maven repo for the group and load my plugin there, but that seems overkill for a single hacky plugin.

Thoughts?

---

I've played with doing it via three different plugins so far:

- `addjars-maven-plugin:add-jars`

  ```
  <plugin>
     <groupId>com.googlecode.addjars-maven-plugin</groupId>
     <artifactId>addjars-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.4</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
           <goals>
              <goal>add-jars</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
              <resources>
                 <resource>
                    <directory>${basedir}/plugins</directory>
                 </resource>
              </resources>
           </configuration>
        </execution>
     </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```

Gives me this error during `mvn build`:

`[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'edu.clemson.cs.rsrg:git-plugin' from the repositories [local (/home/hamptos/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository`

It also causes my later formatting plugin to fail.  (Clearly it's read the jar and determined the group name/plugin name, but then it goes and looks for it in my local repo?  Of course it's not there--I'm trying to install it.)

- `build-helper:attach-artifacts`

  ```
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.7</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
           <id>attach-artifacts</id>
           <phase>install</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
              <artifacts>
                 <artifact>
                    <file>${basedir}/plugins/git-plugin-0.1.0a.jar</file>
                    <type>jar</type>
                 </artifact>
              </artifacts>
           </configuration>
        </execution>
     </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```

Gives me this error during `mvn build`:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:attach-artifact (attach-artifacts) on project RESOLVE: Execution attach-artifacts of goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:attach-artifact failed: For artifact {edu.clemson.cs.rsrg:RESOLVE:12.09.01a:jar}: An attached artifact must have a different ID than its corresponding main artifact.`

(RESOLVE:12.09.01a being the main project.  Clearly something's gone awry here because the plugin and main project definitely have different artifactIDs.  Trying to attach the project on top of itself maybe?)

- `maven-install-plugin:install-file`

  ```
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.1</version>
     <executions>
        <execution>
           <id>install-git-plugin</id>
           <phase>initialize</phase>
           <goals>
              <goal>install-file</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
              <file>${basedir}/plugins/git-plugin-0.1.0a.jar</file>
              <packaging>jar</packaging>
              <groupId>edu.clemson.cs.rsrg</groupId>
              <artifactId>git-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>0.1.0a</version>
           </configuration>
        </execution>
     </executions>
  </plugin>
  ```

Seems to work fine until I try to invoke one of the goals like `mvn edu.clemson.cs.rsrg:git-plugin:rebase`, at which point it gives me this error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal edu.clemson.cs.rsrg:git-plugin:0.1.0a:rebase (default-cli) on project RESOLVE: Execution default-cli of goal edu.clemson.cs.rsrg:git-plugin:0.1.0a:rebase failed: Unable to load the mojo 'rebase' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'edu.clemson.cs.rsrg:git-plugin:0.1.0a': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1) Error in ComponentFactory:ant-mojo
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>edu.clemson.cs.rsrg:git-plugin:0.1.0a, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@e776f7]
[ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=edu.clemson.cs.rsrg:git-plugin:0.1.0a:rebase)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think it is hacky, but it is the maven way. It needs to be deployed to a maven repo.

If you keep it in a groupId that you can demonstrably own and it's open source you can [publish it to central](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide)

Comment: To be clear, I said my plugin was hacky.  I said creating a repository was overkill.  ;)

Comment: Let's presume I was willing to go that route--is setting up a repository relatively straightforward?

Comment: Easy as pie if you use one of the maven repository managers (nexus, artifactory or archivia)... Oh and friends don't let friends use maven without a repository manager. Quit fighting maven on this one... You will loose (note I am a maven committer and on the project management committee)

Comment: Long term I could see us setting up a repo.  For now maybe you can recommend a more direct route to my end goal: ultimately all I'm trying to do is define a maven goal that corresponds to typing "git rebase master" on the command line.  (Overcoming Eclipse/Netbeans deficiencies with that command.  The undergrads get scared at the command line.)  I see I can bind an ant task to a LIFECYCLE PHASE with the ant-run plugin, but that doesn't meet my needs.  Is there a way to do this in Maven 3 that doesn't involve a plugin and a repo?

Comment: Publish your plugin to central. Maven core technology resolves plugins from either the local cache (which is what "install" populates) or a remote repo (which is what "deploy" populates). A plugin must be in one of those two locations to be used by a build. The local cache is just that, local, so you need to push to a remote repo... (the remote repo *could* be just a http server, but you will feel lots of pain).., it could be central if you don't mind the plugin being OSS... If none of those fit you *must* run your own

Comment: I'd be overjoyed to contribute to the Maven community (and everything we do at Clemson is BSD).  That said, I hesitate both because the plugin quality is extremely low (this is an absolute first attempt and it's something I threw together to hack a workaround for a specific set of systems rather than a general solution--any time I use ant exec I get VERRRRY nervous) and because I'm not particularly interested in maintaining the plugin beyond our needs at Clemson (I've got a dissertation to write, after all.)  Is central a place for "any old thing"?

Comment: If you keep it in your groupId, nothing wrong with pushing to central. I have one or two shitty plugins pushed to central under "my" griupId "com.guthub.stephenc" and they are there because they are shitty... If they get good enough I will commit them to either mojo or maven ;-)

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the advice.  If you'll make an edit to your answer to the effect of "If you keep it in your own group ID and it's open source, the easiest thing is just add it to central," I'll happily accept your answer.