# Can I add plugins to maven 3 without installing them

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I would like to add an altered maven plugin to my project.
It contains a feature not yet available in the central repository.
I've tried adding it with system scope and installing it in a local repo, but it doesn't work.
Is this feasible or do I have to install the plugin on every machine I want to build this project on?

The git repo can be found here:
https://github.com/Crydust/DukesShoppingList

**update**
According to "[Maven 3 - Distribute custom plugin in a .jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375952/maven-3-distribute-custom-plugin-in-a-jar)" This requires a maven repo outside of my project. Which would make me sad if true.

**update**
I ended up getting it to work.

```
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomee/tomee/tags/tomee-1.5.2 tomee
cd ~/Projects/tomee/maven

patch tomee-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/maven/plugin/AbstractTomEEMojo.java < ~/Downloads/add_classpaths_config.diff
# fix rejected parts of patch
vim tomee-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/maven/plugin/AbstractTomEEMojo.java
# change version
vim tomee-maven-plugin/pom.xml

mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=repositoryId::default::file:///home/kristof/Projects/tomee/maven/repo/
```

Now I copied the repo folder to my other project and added the pluginRepositories (not the repositories tag) to my pom.

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>repo</id>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

It still works after removing the installed plugin from the local repo.

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/openejb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use your github repository as maven repository.

I found a small manula about it - http://blog.rueedlinger.ch/2012/09/use-github-as-maven-remote-repository/

With small difference, you need to specify the repository plugins:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>Dukes Shopping List Github Repo</id>
        <url>http://your-repository</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```